# Get image Src from the clicked DIV using jQuery

Tags: jquery, image, selector

Yep, it's me again :)

I want to put the src of an image indise a div on double-click.

Here is how it is:

```
<div class="explorer_icon"><img src="here.png"/></div>
```

When we double-click on the div, the src of the image is returned.

How can i do that?

Here is what i tried, no success, as you can guess.

```
$('div.explorer_icon').dblclick(function() {
    editor($(this).attr('img src'));
});
$('div.explorer_icon').dblclick(function() {
    editor($(this).attr('src'));
});
$('div.explorer_icon').dblclick(function() {
    editor($('img').attr('src'));
});
```

Can you help me on this please?
Thank you!

Comment: Thanks Patrick dw, I don't know why it didn't save the div/image code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Traverse down from the div and get the image, then get it's src attribute.

```
$('div.explorer_icon').dblclick(function(){
  editor($(this).children('img').attr('src'));
});
```

Need to remember that within your even `$(this)` is the div. Since the image resides within it (is a child) you need to locate it, then grab it's attribute.

Comment: OMG! Thanks! I was looking on the jquery website for something like this. But never find it. Thank you so much

Comment: You're Welcome! And if this was what you were looking for make sure to mark the answer accepted (same with your previous questions it appears) so anyone else that may find this question knows what answer was the correct one.

Comment: Yeah i know, but Stackoverflow sais : Wait 8 minutes before marking this question as accepted. But i'll do it right now :)

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

**Javascript:**

```
$('#test img').dblclick(function() {
    $(this).parent().append($(this).attr('src'));
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="test">
    <img src="http://sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon.png" />
</div>
```